# Как в Linux клонировать диск в диск другого размера

Tags: linux, hdd, диск, ssd, клонирование

Имеем Linux - Fedora 22,
HDD - на котором установлена система, 
требуется переехать на SDD который в два раза меньшего размера, но данных на HDD мало, поэтому влезут.
Оба диска подключены к компьютеру.
Вопрос: как клонировать диск? Желательно средствами GNU Linux.

Уточнения:
1. CD/DVD - нет.
2. gparted - не работает с активным системным разделом.
3. Куда tar архив размещать? в /dev/null ? два диска всего.
4. Диски разного размера!

Comment: Попробуйте эту ссылку http://blog.oaktreepeak.com/2012/03/move_your_linux_installation_t.html

Comment: dd if=откуда of=куда

Comment: Загружаешься с livecd, монтируешь существующий hdd, весь hdd пакуешь в tar, монтируешь ssd, распаковываешь tar на ssd.

Дальше самое интересное, нужно указать grub откуда грузиться. Примерно так

    mount -t proc none /mnt/ssd/proc
    mount -o bind /sys /mnt/ssd/sys
    mount -o bind /dev /mnt/ssd/dev
    chroot /mnt/ssd /bin/bash
    grub
    root (hd0,0)
    setup (hd0)

/mnt/ssd - примонтированый ssd

Comment: gparted вам а помощь

Comment: @2ray а что будет с данными, которые оказались в конце HDD?

Comment: кстати как вариант `dump | restore`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все можно сделать, главное аккуратно. Нужны следующие вещи:

- livecd диск или лучше флешка. Можно другого совместимого дистрибутива, к примеру ubuntu.
- оба диска должны быть подключены к компу.

Процедура переноса.

- загрузится с live
- открыть gparted или любую другую любимую утилиту для разбивки диска.
- разбить ssd как нужно (home, root, swap и дальше по предпочтениям), отформатировать
- монтируем новые диски и старые. Рекомендую сделать в /mount папку old (для старого диска) и new (для нового).
- копируем данные. Так как это линукс, то можно с помощью cp, главное сохранить права. К примеру home `cp -a /mount/old/home/ /mount/new/home`.
- аналогично копируется корень. Но тут есть особеность - не все нужно копировать. к примеру, папку tmp не нужно (хотя ничего плохого не будет). Если в папка /mount/old/proc и /mount/old/sys что то будет внутри - это копировать не нужно (содержимое этих папок система создает сама).
- не забываем о boot разделе.
- если имена устройств поменялись (к примеру, home это был /dev/sda*1*, а стал /dev/sdb*4* - тут важна цифра, а не буква), то открываем файл `/mount/new/etc/fstab` и правим по феншую.
- осталось последнее - перенести загрузочную запись. Вначале копируем старый `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/to/mbr_file.img bs=512 count=1`, а потом переносим на новый. Так как мы не хотим потереть таблицу разделов, то нужно не все скопировать. `dd if=/path/to/mbr_file.img of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1`.

Все, можно выключать, поставить диски по местам, поправить в биосе загрузочное устройство и пробовать.

Что делать, если ничего не завелось?

Старый диск скорее всего не поврежден. Так что им можно будет загрузиться. Плюс есть флешка. Можно восстановить.

Но если честно, то я переносил немного по другому. Все как выше, разбил диск, скопировал home раздел, потом вытянул старый диск, и загрузился с флешки. И начал установку как обычно. В процессе установки главное не отформатировать home раздел (хотя потом все равно можно скопировать). Так как home раздел есть, то сохранятся все настройки программ. Потом только возможно нужно будет доустановить недостающие программы.

Comment: Видать за столько лет в Linux так и не придумали ничего лучше платного акрониса. Одни костыли.

Comment: Переносил я и акронисом. Потом все равно пришлось допиливать fdisk'ом.

Comment: @dsnk Почему сразу костыли. Есть gparted, который умеет не только размечать диск на разделы, но и копировать разделы.

Comment: умеет. И даже можно было все сделать им. Но я считаю, что при переносе старый диск лучше не портить.

Comment: @tutankhamun для gparted потребуется искать liveCD + USB привод, либо городить пол дня Flash-ку загрузочную. Т.е. просто так взять и сделать нельзя.

Comment: загрузочная флешка делается за 10 минут.

Comment: @KoVadim с установленной на неё ОС и требуемыми утилитами? у меня ОС дольше инсталлируется. А ещё такую Flash-ку теперь надо купить.

Comment: @dsnk Странная контрмотивация. Вы не автор Акрониса случайно?

Comment: на лайвсиди уже есть все нужные утилиты.

Comment: На стандартном liveCD от федоры22 не нашёл gparted.

Comment: Нужен liveCD от gparted

Comment: @tutankhamun дайте ссылку.

Comment: @dnsk http://gparted.org/livecd.php Можно грузиться хоть с usb, хоть с CD-привода, хоть из сети

Comment: Если какой то утилиты нет, а она нужна, так как по другому ну никак, то всегда можно установить с помощью yum/dnf. Да, оно будет до перезагрузки, но какая разница?

Comment: @tutankhamun Благодарю, пойду искать Flash-ку.

Comment: если не хочется пользоваться флешкой, на борту почти любого *никса есть `dump` & `restore`

Comment: @tutankhamun нет желания разбираться с LVM томами.

Answer (score 2):

Очень рекомендую присмотреться к проекту [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/).
 Умеет копировать как линуксовые, так и виндовые разделы. Грузится с флэшки, болванки, сети, умеет работать в режиме сервера и раздавать образ через мультикаст. Запускается в режиме мастера, на русский переведено подавляющее большинство диалогов.

Да, может понадобиться тем же `gparted live` ужать разделы до размеров влезающих на ssd, но остальные `dd` и `cp -r` там не нужны. Есть режим копирования с железки на железку, можно сначала в образ, а потом из образа.

Comment: Спасибо за совет насчет Clonezilla. К сожалению, это слишком простой инструмент, чтобы им пользоваться практически. Читаем первое же ограничение: "The destination partition must be equal or larger than the source one."