# Как создать резервную копию всего сервера ubuntu 9 с помощью Live CD?

Tags: ubuntu

Имеется сервер с ubuntu 9 без графической оболочки, логина и пароля к нему нет, надо сделать полную резервную копию сервера использую Live CD. Как это сделать?
Можно ли подключить HDD сервера к компьютеру с Ubuntu с графической оболочкой и сделать ctrl+c ctrl+v?

Comment: Можно сделать образ диска с помощью утилиты dd

Comment: Загрузиться с LiveCD и сдампить весь диск каким-нибудь Acronis'ом или чем-то подобным. Если это именно сервер (железка, а не ОС), то там скорее всего рейд, его так просто к компу не подключишь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала надо ответ дать на вопрос - с какой целью снимается дамп (копия) сервера?

Например, дамп может быть нужен для целей восстановления данных или криминалистики

1. Самый простой, но не обязательно правильный путь - подключить второй накопитель и использовать утилиту `dd`. В качестве аргумента if указываете исходный накопитель, а в качестве of - или файл, или накопитель-назначение (объемом не меньше изначального).
   Пример команды: `dd if=/dev/sdb of=usb-image.dsk`
2. Чуть менее простой. Качаем Acronis TrueImage в виде загрузочного ISO диска и снимаем им посекторную копию диска. Минусы в том, что если Acronis не знает файловую систему, то образ будет объемом как исходный винчестер. Если знает, то он может свободное место на файловой системе не копировать и образ будет занимать ровно столько места, сколько сами файлы.
3. Сделать пофайловую копию любой из утилит резервного копирования под Linux. Их список можно найти [здесь](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-outstanding-linux-backup-utilities/). Самая стандартная из них - `rsync`. Учитывая, что они делают пофайловый образ, то из него всегда можно вытянуть произвольный файл.

Comment: Копирование нужно целью восстановления работоспособности на этом же сервере. То есть, я хочу на сервер поставить другую систему, но нужна возможность восстановления всех данных до переустановки. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Один из моих "домашних" вариантов - дамп диска по `ssh`. Долго, нудно, но иногда другого выхода нет. Бонус в том, что сервер можно не развинчивать:

```
  dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1M | ssh -carcfour128 X.Y.Z.Q 'dd of=/srv/backups/server.big'
```

Тут у нас два экземпляра `dd`, первый работает на 'доноре' и передает данные через `stdio` в `ssh`. `ssh` запускает на 'приемнике' `dd` и пишет данные в обычный файл.

`-carcfour128` заставляет `ssh` использовать менее монструозный шифр при передаче данных. Так что если защита вам не важна, можете выиграть по скорости процентов 20.

Answer (score 1):

Похожая проблема уже была. Есть решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456432/191416. Это удобнее и быстрее `dd`.