# Унификация окружения для разных машин в глобальной сети

Tags: windows, сеть, развертывание

Есть много машин в глобальный сети с windows embeded (win7 x86). Все крутят одну програмку которая выполняет одну задачу. Все настройки винды и установленные библиотеки и версия програмки должны быть идентичны. 
Вопрос: есть ли способ разпространять изменения на все эти машины?
Может это будет образ системы на флешке, который можно будет залить через интернет и прошить с помошью какого-то супервизора?

UPD1:

1. Изменения могут касаться установки\удаления драйверов и установки апдейтов. Ну и есть возможность тушить.
2. Под либами понимаются не только либы которые использует приложение, но и всё окружение. Типа обновление версии .Net Framework
3. Есть эталон который нужно распространить.
4. Изначально они в глобальной сети интернет. Можно реализовать впн или ещё что-либо, что потребуется. Без физического присутствия.

Эти пожелания - идеал, любые предложения, даже не подходящие на 100%, принимаются.

Comment: Изменения должны применяться на лету или машину, на которую надо залить софт\настройки можно потушить, прогрузить что-либо и потом включить ОС?

Comment: Прога и либы должны быть установлены или годится свалить их в одну папку и просто перетаскивать?

Comment: Есть мастер-комп с эталонными настройками, которые должны кидаться на остальные компы или в процессе работы все настройки всех машин тоже надо учитывать\распространять?

Comment: Как организована сеть между 2 (3,4,n) этими машинами? Прямой доступ, vpn, proxy, отдельная оптика, etc?

Comment: Ответы лучше оформить в виде обновления вопроса.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enterprise way**: Включить все машины в [AD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) и кидать конфиги, софт, файлы через [GPO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Лучше всё это ещё и в VPN завернуть.

Плюсы:

1. По AD\GPO куча доков как официальных, так и пользовательских.
2. Гибкая и мощная штука, которая как раз для этого и была разработана.

Минусы:

1. Надо где-то крутить желательно пару нод AD, чтобы отказоустойчивость и всё такое. Ну т.е. на разных физических машинах (пусть и внутри виртуалок)
2. Настраивать методом тыка - очень сложно.
3. Цена лицензии кусается (если лицензионность важна).

**Бомж way №1.**
[BTSync](https://www.getsync.com/)\ [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) + пачка самописных cmd.

Схема такая: везде ставим прогу для синхронизации, в папку\папки закидываем нужный софт, скрипты, конфиги. На клиентах настраиваем, чтобы оно как-то выполнялось (по планировщику, триггеру, при перезагрузке, руками через rdp/TW/AmmyAdmin, запускали местные эникейщики)

Плюсы:

1. 100% лицензионно (если это важно).
2. Просто добавлять новые фишки: просто закинь новый текстовый файл, просто добавь ещё одну строку `call script-10.cmd`

Минусы:

1. Неизвестно на сколько хорошо оно выполнится на конкретной машине (не значит, что вообще всё плохо, просто на одной может начать что-нибудь выполняться, что помешает самопальному скрипту запуститься или правильно отработать)
2. Некоторые инсталляторы не поддерживают "тихий режим" и тогда придётся шаманить уже с обёртками типа [AutoIt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) или exe2msi. Впрочем этот минус актуален и для энтерпрайза.

**Бомж way №2.** Метод образов.

Схема такая: берём эталонную машину, настраиваем там всё, что можно настроить (системные настройки, кнопки\менюшки), [добавляем](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=pnputil)\устанавливаем все дрова, которые могут понадобиться (на разные видюхи, принтеры, контроллеры), [запаковываем в образ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456432/191416) вообще всё (загрузчик, таблицу разделов, сами разделы) и раскатываем на клиентах. Меняем хостнеймы, настройки сети по надобности

Плюсы:

1. Понятный интерфейс настройки: просто настраиваем одну машину привычным образом - никаких GPO, скриптов, cmd, powershell и прочих regedit. Надо много раз натыкать мышкой по нужным кнопкам.
2. Если образ сделан грамотно и там нет мусора - весит мало, разворачивается быстро (быстрее, чем установка винды, установка обновлений, установка прог даже в полностью тихом режиме) и с гарантированным результатом, что программы, иконки, настройки никуда не денутся.

Минусы:

1. Если обновлять, то вообще весь раздел или диск. Удалится всё, что не успели сохранить.
2. Сделать это удалённо **очень** хитровытяннутая (но возможная) задача. Легче дойти ногами и развернуть. Так что если компы географически разнесены - или командировка или местные эникейщики или комп привозят в головной офис, образ накатывается, комп отвозится на место.

**Даже не знаю в какую сторону way №3.** [Puppet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet) 4 Windows.

Штука хороша для управления линуксовыми машинами (поддерживает дистроспецифичные фишки типа менеджера пакетов и структуры в /etc). Как запустится на винде и как будет работать - ни малейшего понятия, хотя клиенты для [x86](https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/windows/puppet-agent-x86-latest.msi) и [amd64](https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/windows/puppet-agent-x64-latest.msi) есть. Лично я пробовал виндовый вариант пару лет назад. Файлы создавать получалось и даже msi какую-то запускал. До более серьёзных сценариев так к сожалению и не добрался, так что реальных практик не подскажу.

Плюсы:

1. Прога создавалась как раз как GPO4UNIX ну или типа того, так что в неё уже зашиты механизмы по управлению, мониторингу и контролю за конфигурацией системы.
2. СПО (если важно).
3. Есть куча пользовательских обёрток, манифестов и утилит для работы с этой системой. Большинство на Гитхабе.

Минусы:

1. Применительно в твоём случае надо смотреть как клиенты будут отрабатывать под виндой.
2. Поверхностное гугление в рунете именно про связку windows+puppet дало плачевные результаты. Или я плохо искал или все действительно перепостивают друг у друга хеллоуворлды.

---

Вообще можно комбинировать: сначала делаем эталонный образ, после разворота скриптом включем его в домен, ждём, пока применятся специфичные политики и отвозим на точку.

P.S. Может ещё что допишу.

Comment: Можешь расписать немного этот момент: "чтобы оно как-то выполнялось"? Прогу которая будет запускать батники из папки(только новые только один раз) или клиент-сервер систему чтобы просто указать батник который надо запустить у всех.

Comment: @I.V.S., добавил про puppet. Если не хочешь AD, я бы на твоём месте ковырнул бы именно паппет.

Comment: Покопался сам немного, вот хорошее сравнение разных пакетов: [ссылка](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) Пока не нашел подходящий. Самые известные: Puppet, Chef, Salt требуют Linux-servera, но клиенты есть под винду. К тому же есть бесплатные варианты использования.

Comment: @I.V.S., да, я сам находил эту таблицу. Везде, что я успел прочитать - puppet уделывает по фичастости всех. Было бы неплохо увидеть тут тех, кто именно на винде перепробовал всех клиентов и может рассказать свой опыт.

Не вижу ничего плохого в управляющем сервере на linux. Лично для меня - это наоборот достоинство.

Comment: Да, не стоит всё-таки выставлять клиенты винды напрямую в сеть. Даже Майкрософт это не рекомендует и пропускала свои сервера через фаерволл основанный на openbsd. Позаботься о промежуточном звене или вообще VPN.

Comment: @I.V.S., https://habrahabr.ru/post/267617/ - вот. Puppet с web-интерфейсом.