# Как перенести linux ubuntu на флешку

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, ос

У меня на пк установлен ubuntu linux 16.04 x64. Есть ли способ перенести данную систему на флешку, сохранив все настройки и программы, затем полноценно ее запускать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456432/191416

Comment: Насколько я слышал, то юзать ОС на флешке — не самый лучший вариант в силу того, что система будет постоянно писать файлы, а флешки, в свою очередь, на такое не рассчитаны; то есть есть вероятность, что флешка ляснет через некоторое время. А вообще, раньше тот же Startup Disk Creator позволял создавать загрузочные флешки с резервацией места под сохранение данных, то есть получалась полноценная ОС, а не зарузочный диск,.. оставалось только установить софт и юзаться. Возможно сейчас такое можно провернуть через UNetbootin (место точно можно зарезервировать, но не знаю будет ли его ...

Comment: ... использовать система) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UNetbootin** - Установите эту програрамму из стандартного репозитария и она создаст загрузочную флэшку. Далее можете писать туда все файлы, которые считаете необходимыми.

Или второй вариант - создать ISO образ Вашей системы и уже его записать на флэшку.