# Как перенести linux на другую машину?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть linux mint на ноутбуке, пользуюсь уже полгода, сейчас нужно перенести систему со всеми программами на пк (можно установить с 0 и все настроить, но слишком долго). Драйвера как и железо совершенно разные. Хотелось бы взять снапшот без драйверов и развернуть его на пк с последующим обновление драйверов под нужную машину

Comment: Драйвера в линукс!? там все не так, как в виндовс. Может, просто склонировать раздел диска с линуксом на новый раздел нового компьютера? например, https://youtu.be/hzjF1NYCk0Y

Comment: если архитектура процессоров идентична, то просто переставьте винчестер(ы).

Answer (score 1):

Лично я пользуюсь [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456432/191416) с 2011-го года. Перевалило за 1к разворачиваний образов на разное железо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете осуществить перенос и вручную, разными способами.

1. Подключить два hdd к одному компьютеру и скопировать с одного на другой с помощью dd
2. С помощью livecd загрузиться на новом компьютере, создать разделы, примонтировать, скопировать данные с помощью rsync по сети или локально. Вариацией на тему будет создание и распаковка tar архива. 
   После чего вам нужно будет установить загрузчик, поправить /etc/fstab, и, возможно, обновить initramfs.

Если вы используете generic ядро и у вас не стоит проприетарных драйверов (nvidia\amd) то скорее всего касательно драйверов вам ничего делать не придётся

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой *ignite-lx* (Есть на GitHub, я соразработчик там). Она как раз для этих случаев.

Comment: Эта https://github.com/deatwisedog/ignite-lx? Гугл вообще роликовые коньки показывает. ))

Comment: Да, оно самое =)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще перенос что винды начиная с 7-ки, что линя, как бы не должны вызывать проблем. На уровне системы всё подхватывается. Ну может не идеально, но достаточно для того что бы загрузиться. Если просто склонировать диск то проблемы подозреваю будут в двух случаях, с новыми защитами нового биоса (того что uefi) и если при установке были указаны dev id, а не стандартные sdХ. Тогда придётся индивидуально думать на тему реанимации загрузчика.

Или установить систему и скопировать нужные файлы из etc чем восстановить большую часть настроек.