# Копирование жесткого диска командами Linux

Tags: linux, hdd

Нужно перенести все данные со старого HDD (`sdX`) на новый SSD (`sdY`).

Используется GPT. Места на новом диске больше либо равно чем на старом. Есть несколько разделов: загрузочный, несколько виндовых, несколько линуксовых. Нужно перенести их все в первозданном виде, один из них по необходимости увеличить.

1. Можно ли сначала скопировать весь диск как есть, байт в байт, а затем *GParted*'ом увеличить один из разделов, чтобы занять неразмеченную область?
2. Какую из команд лучше использовать для копирования?

   `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY
   cp /dev/sdX /dev/sdY
   cat /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY`

Или какую-то другую? Я знаю, что обычно используют `dd`, но она вроде медленная.

Comment: dd или cat. И dd не медленная, если bs несколько мегабайт сделать. но кроме увеличения раздела parted может потребоваться последующее расширение самой файловой системы в разделе отдельными утилитами, зависящими от файловой системы

Comment: Какими утилитами расширить ext4?

Comment: попробуйте gparted - графический интерфейс и все что нужно.

Comment: А разве он это умеет?

Comment: @KoVadim У меня тот же вопрос, это вроде как не его дело немного.

Comment: google по запросу "resize ext4" выдал статьи в которых сказано, что достаточно после расширения раздела выполнить `resize2fs /dev/sdX`

Comment: Да, gparted все нужное умеет, сам переносил с HDD на SSD.

Comment: @Mike Только там же надо номер раздела указать `/dev/sdX1`

Comment: @Mike, *dd или cat* — а программа *cp* чем вам не угодила? 2автор-вопроса: какой вариант использовать во втором пункте — несущественно. а существенно то, что ни один раздел на этих блочных устройствах не должен быть примонтирован.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это очевидно, что надо отмонтировать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456432/191416

Comment: bmaptools довольно быстрая и навороченная программа.

Comment: А можно ли сначала скопировать таблицу разделов,
`sgdisk -R /dev/sdY /dev/sdX`
А затем скопировать каждый отельный раздел
`cat /dev/sdX2 > /dev/sdY2 ;
cat /dev/sdX3 > /dev/sdY3 ;
...`?

Comment: Сделал, как тут написано. Не работает. Не грузится ни одна система. Копировать диск с GPT надо как-то иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда переношу с помощью `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=20M`, а расширяю файловую систему в **gparted** в графическом интерфейсе.

Можно также использовать "онлайн" расширение файловой системы на весь раздел -  `resize2fs /dev/sdbX`.

Сначала надо растянуть раздел.

Захожу в `gdisk /dev/sdb` и выполняю `p` - просмотр таблицы разделлов. Потом удаляю раздел который надо растянуть. И создаю его заново только нужно чтоб совпало начало раздела, а конец был дальше чем размеченно в файловой системе. Потом сделать `resize2fs /dev/sdbX`