# Резервное инкрементальное копирование жесткого диска через Linux CLI

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, hdd

Существует проблема элементарного резервного копирования жесткого диска с ОС Windows на внешний винчестер. Использовал разные версии Acronis и аналоги, крайне неудовлетворен их работой с ошибками. Изучаю линукс и поэтому хочу узнать:

Как проще всего бэкапить винчестер целиком, используя консоль линукс-дистрибутива(debian), чтобы создавались последующие инкрементальные бэкапы жесткого диска?

Нагуглил программу rsnapshot, через нее научился бэкапить отдельные папки\раделы жесткого диска. Но не могу понять как бэкапить весь винчестер с EFI\MBR- и прочими системными разделами.

Comment: Вообще задача инкрементального копирования всего диска целиком не  тривиальная. дело в том, что в конкретном разделе есть файловая система и в ней у файлов есть дата модификации, по которой утилиты инкрементального копирования понимают, что копировать, а что нет. Но на сыром диске ничего подобного нет и единственный способ сделать инкрементальную копию это сравнить весь диск целиком с предыдущей копией. Если копия лежит тут же на другом диске - это еще спокойно выполнимо, но если она например на сетевом диске ...

Comment: Если бы у меня была подобная задача я бы взял наверное старый добрый rsync. это только кажется, что он умеет только файлы копировать. но в качестве файла ему вполне можно дать /dev/sda. при этом можно ключами указать ему, что бы он не писал новый файл, а писал только отличия старого файла от нового, вот вам и инкрементальная копия. Только я бы сначала на кошках тренировался, вроде какой нибудь флешке, на случай если параметры окажутся не правильными и он решит что нибудь потереть на /dev/sda ...

Comment: для справки: загрузочный cd/dvd/usb от компании acronis — это та же самая операционная система gnu/linux. со специализированными программами, конечно. некоторые из которых — проприетарные, написанные программистами из компании acronis. если вас не устраивают результаты работы этих программ, вы, конечно, можете написать что-нибудь «более лучшее», но вряд ли вам удастся как-то радикально «переплюнуть» программистов из компании acronis. хотя проприетарный код, это конечно, то ещё «чудо». да и задача у вас будет несколько иная, чем ставят маркетологи перед программистами.

Comment: Разделите задачу на несколько.  Домашний каталог можно копировать через tar, а вот mbr обычно маленький и его можно просто как раздел забекапить

Comment: Ооо! Моя любимая тема на которой я съел собак больше, чем любой кореец!

Comment: @Mike, rsync хорош для linux, потому что умеет `ACL` и `ugo`, а виндовый acl он не умеет. Так что пролёт.

Comment: @donRumata А зачем нужен ACL если мы бекапим сырой диск, а не файловую систему. нам нужен двоичный образ файла (диска) и более ничего. никаких прав доступа и ACL. Плюс конечно самое главное, возможность записи только изменений по сравнению с образом, что так же обеспечено

Comment: @Mike, в последнем предложении написано, что человек хочет и системные тоже.

Comment: @donRumata правильно. так я предлагаю делать `rsync /dev/sda ....` т.е. весь диск целиком, вместе с MBR и любыми разделами. И для rsync это будет просто большой файл, все права доступа и прочее для него будут просто обычными данными внутри файла и не более

Comment: @Mike, т.е. терабайтный винт с занятыми 20 гигами будет весить терабайт?

Comment: @donRumata `rsync ... | bzip2 ...` вот и нет терабайта. хотя согласен, это излишне. Но все таки просили полный образ диска как у acronis. на диске вполне могут быть интересные данные даже в неразмеченных областях и акронис их сохранит (я надеюсь)

Comment: @Mike, я просто копирую виндовые разделы локально\по сети уже скоро как 7 лет. И варианты вида `dd if=/dev/sda of=file | xz -9` я встречаю чуть ли не в каждом обсуждении о резервоном копировании разделов. И это УЖАСНЫЙ вариант. Он хорош, когда остальное просто отказывается работать. Но тогда надо уже смотреть в сторону железа - обычно оно начинает косячить.

Comment: @donRumata dd все таки немного хуже, он не умеет делать инкрементального бекапа. хотя что бы rsync сделал инкремент целевой файл должен существовать и не должен быть сжат. так что придется использовать сжатие на уровне фс на целевой системе, что не всегда возможно. хотя я пожалуй просто сделал бы небольшой патчик к rsync что бы большие пустые области не писать. Остается самое сложное - узнать что область пуста. не факт что не используемые области будут содержать нули. А все что не ноль все таки лучше считать полезными данными

Comment: @Mike "вы хотите рабочий вариант? их есть у меня". Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: @donRumata Кстати, у rsync есть ключик sparse ... надо бы посмотреть как он устроен. если он их "поддерживает" именно так, как я надеюсь,  тогда 20 мб из терабайта будут выглядеть на целевой ФС как терабайт, но при этом по блокам будут занимать 20 мб.

Comment: @Mike, напиши опции rsync, которые по твоему мнению помогут нормально закопировать виндовый раздел, я на тестовой машине попробую и расскажу что получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответил тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456432/191416

По поводу <s>инкрементности</s> дедупликации - есть `zbackup`, но он как-то плохо работает или я не смог его приготовить. С диффами именно разделов ничего стоящего не видел.

**UPD1**. Лично я пришёл к такой архитектуре по поводу ОС, клонирования бэкапов и системы:

1. Автоматизация.

   1.1. Установка не должна занимать много сил и времени. Если всё-таки занимает, то надо сделать, чтобы мало занимала именно ВАШЕГО времени.

   1.2. Переустановка - тем более.

   1.3. Нажимать много кнопок - плохо. Мало - хорошо. Идеал - одна кнопка. Конечная цель - вообще без кнопок.
2. Операционка и софт не важны.
3. Важны только пользовательские данные.

   3.1. По возможности ничего не хранить локально. Но если не получается - сделать максимум для того, чтобы данные можно было легко вытащить. В том числе и автоматически.
4. KISS.
5. Файлы - отдельно, проги - отдельно.
6. Базовый функционал одинаков для всех, остальное добавляется по мере надобности. Желательно автоматически.
7. Добавлять компоненты, которые помогут автоматизации и тестированию проблем.
8. Максимальная переносимость. Начиная 1-м DDR и заканчивая последним поддерживаемым.

Ничего нового, но если это заработает - копировать целые винты не понадобится от слова "вообще". Под это всё попадает: AD, GPO, ansible, общие папки и деплой винды по сети (только по ней и никак иначе).